# Could not load type 'Facebook.FacebookApplication' from assembly

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to use the Facebook assemblies in ASP.NET MVC 3.
I'm following this tutorial: http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started
but when I'm trying to use one of his functions as this one...

```
[FacebookAuthorize(LoginUrl = "...")]
    public abstract class SuperController<T> : Controller where T : BaseRequirement
{
...
}
```

when other controllers inherit from it, I get an exception.
The exception:

```
Could not load type 'Facebook.FacebookApplication' from assembly 'Facebook, Version=6.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Facebook.FacebookApplication' from assembly 'Facebook, Version=6.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Facebook.FacebookApplication' from assembly 'Facebook, Version=6.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de'.]
   Facebook.Web.Mvc.FacebookAuthorizeAttributeBase.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) in e:\Prabir\Documents\Projects\facebooksdk\v5.3.2\Source\Facebook.Web.Mvc\FacebookAuthorizeAttributeBase.cs:44
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8969201
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

I tried to update from Nuget and check if I'm using the last version and I think it's ok.
In my app.config I found this:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Facebook" publicKeyToken="58cb4f2111d1e6de" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.10.0" newVersion="6.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FacebookAuthorize` has been removed in v6.

You can find v6 samples at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-aspnet-sample and https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-canvas-aspnet-sample